# Request for Member 'View' in something not a structure or union

Tags: objective-c, ios, viewcontroller

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title.

Here's my interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ControllerLevel1;

@interface RootController : UIViewController {
ControllerLevel1 *controllerLevel1;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) ControllerLevel1 *controllerLevel1;

@end
```

And here's the implementation:

```
#import "RootController.h"
#import "ControllerLevel1.h"

@implementation RootController

@synthesize controllerLevel1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ControllerLevel1 *firstLevel = [[ControllerLevel1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ControllerLevel1" bundle:nil];
    self.controllerLevel1 = firstLevel;
    [self.view insertSubview:firstLevel.view atIndex:0];
    [firstLevel release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The error occurs in `[self.view insertSubview:firstLevel.view atIndex:0];`

Comment: What is ControllerLevel1? Do you have your code from that class. Is it a UIViewController subclass?

Comment: It is a UIViewController subclass. Other than the "template" provided when you create a new set of .h and .m files, there is no other code.

Comment: Let's see the .h file, at least the instance vars and properties portion of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining about firstLevel.view.

So, likely you didn't declare "view" as a property in ControllerLevel1.h.  Show us the .h file for that and we can help more.

Comment: That's all it is:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ControllerLevel1 : UIViewController {

}

@end

Comment: Try passing self.view in place of firstLevel.view just to make sure we are correct that the error is firstLevel.view (yes, don't run this, just compile to see if we do or do not get the warning).  If not, then we are correct that firstLevel.view is the problem.

Comment: I passed self.view in place of firstLevel.view and it compiled just fine. So what's wrong with firstLevel.view? Much thanks for the help so far, btw.

Comment: Seems like it should be working to me.  Look for warnings in the build output?  Maybe crank up the warning levels in project settings?  try build & analyze to see if it'll tell you what it's not liking.   So here's a work-around, but shouldn't have to.  pass [firstLevel view] instead of firstLevel.view.  You shouldn't have to do that though.   what compiler & Xcode version are you using? maybe a compiler bug (?).

Comment: That worked, so I'm going to stick with it for now so I can move on. Much thanks for the help!